# Swift - Converting a Dictionary to a KeyValuePair

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, key-value

I'm trying to use the brand new Swift Chart framework, and the [chartForegroundStyleScale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/chartplotcontent/chartforegroundstylescale(_:)) function takes a [KeyValuePairs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyvaluepairs) as the argument. I tried supplying a Dictionary (of `[String:Color]`, but I get the error `Cannot convert value of type '[String : Color]' to expected argument type 'KeyValuePairs<DataValue, S>'`.

Ok so fair enough, I need to convert the Dictionary to a KeyValuePair. I tried creating the KVP the same way I created the Dictionary, but this doesn't work. I loop through the appropriate array and build a dictionary, but this doesn't work with a KVP as you cannot modify a KVP once it's created. I also need to add around 40 Keys and Pairs to the item, not a single one.

I tried creating a KVP from the dictionary like this

```
 let myKVP = KeyValuePairs(dictionaryLiteral: myDictionary)
```

But this fails with the error `Cannot convert value of type '[String : Color]' to expected argument type '(Key, Value)'`

All the tutorials I find involve typing out and hard coding the KVP data, which isn't possible for me, as the data will be different each time the app opens. So how do I generate a KVP?

Comment: You can’t. There is no way to use a dictionary to instantiate a KeyValuePair

Comment: Unfortunately the only way to generate a KVP is using a dictionary literal.

Comment: @LeoDabus So is there an industry accepted way of creating a KVP dynamically? I can make this work if I hardcode the data, but I don't know how to generate the KeyValurePairs from programmatically from the downloaded data.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson This answer is for entering data into a chart, for not styling it.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen This may be the answer. I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson you're missing the point, you can't pass tuples to `chartForegroundStyleScale` , that's the key problem here. Also if you wanted to just suggest tuples maybe just link to the Swift documentation on Tuples, not a unrelated question for a unrelated function taking a unrelated type.